# How to use KMM Reaktive Single inside native Android Project

Tags: android, kotlin-multiplatform

I have this in my `shared` module

```
fun getAssignedBooks(): SingleWrapper<List<String>> {
        return singleFromCoroutine {
            callAssignedBooks()
        }
            .subscribeOn(ioScheduler)
            .observeOn(mainScheduler)
            .wrap()
    }
```

If I simply call this from my native Android app like so:

```
val assignedBooks = SharedBookRepository().getAssignedBooks()
assignedBooks.subscribe()
```

I get this compile time error on the `.subscribe()` method:

```
Cannot access 'com.badoo.reaktive.base.Source' which is a supertype of 'com.badoo.reaktive.single.SingleWrapper'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
Cannot access 'com.badoo.reaktive.single.Single' which is a supertype of 'com.badoo.reaktive.single.SingleWrapper'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

I saw there's a `com.badoo.reaktive:rxjava2-interop:xxxx` library, but not sure how I would apply it in this case.

I'd like to have both native Android and native Swift projects call this shared module method. The `SingleWrapper` I guess solves that for iOS?! (maybe ?! i don't know) but what about Android?

How can I achieve this? call `getAssignedBooks` from existing native projects ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says that your Android app module doesn't have access to the Reaktive library. You can try one of the following.

1. Define Reaktive dependency as `api` in your `shared` module:

```
kotlin {
    sourceSets {
        commonMain {
            dependencies {
                api("com.badoo.reaktive:reaktive:<version>")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

--- or ---

2. Define the dependency as `implementation` in your Android app module:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("com.badoo.reaktive:reaktive:<version>")
}
```

Comment: I completely forgot about this question, and yes, using `api` did the trick, I eventually figured it out on my own. So thank you !